# Cad plotters and Python

Tags: python, printing, cad

I'm wandering what the best way is to send a fully scaled (1:1) dxf drawing to a cad plotter using python. Has anyone here ever done this?

For those who want to know why:

I've written a program for my employer that automates the drawing of detailed 
schematics, apparently so our engineering dept can spend more time doing nothing. The issue now is that they would like to completely eliminate acad since it's only used to plot the finished drawing.

Mind you these drawings are used for non-trivial things like checking the dimensions of critical components used in commercial jetliners.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythoncad/

Comment: I need some more data to be able to try to help you: Why do you need DXF then? Do the plotter accept it directly? What OS are you using? How is the plotter connected to the system (ethernet/USB/parallel/serial? )

Comment: It's a CAD plotter so it's designed to accept dxf and dwg's as well as standard file types . It's connected via the network and all of the users have windows 7 (unfortunately). Basically I'm trying to recreate the print dialog you get in autocad when you type 'plot'. I could change the drawing to PS or any image format if need be.

Comment: what drawing program do they use? AutoCAD 2010 has an [auto spooler](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f4875513fb5cd10c4aa30d6b-79a0.htm,topicNumber=d0e410197)

Comment: I wrote the drawing program. They're just using AutoCad to print the resulting files. They want me to completely remove acad from the work-flow and have my program print out the drawings. I think I may be close to a solution now, although a really sloppy one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem (pretty unlikely) I though I'd post briefly what I did in the end:

1.) Wrote a short script to capture the dxf as a BMP (basicaly just a screen grab that appends the scale to the drawing)

2.)  Wrote a print dialog with PyQt4 that's a clone of Autocads plot window except that it has to pull the scaling info from the BMP.

My python skills are awfull so there's likely better solutions but this worked.